# How to solve properly a system of nonlinear equations with fsolve in python

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve system of non linear equations.

To do that, I successfully used sympy online to solve a system of three equations. But it didn't work anymore with 7 equations, returning me an "Operation timed out" message.
So, I'm trying to use the standard fsolve in order to solve the problem. But while I have good results with sympy with just a simple set of 3 equations, fsolve gives me bad results.

This is the code I wrote (thanks to what I found on this forum) :

```py
def equations(p):
    w1, w2, m = p
    f0 = w1+w2-1
    f1 = w1*m+w2*(1-2*m)-1/3
    f2 = w1*m**2+w2*(1-2*m)**2-1/5
    return (f0,f1,f2)

w1, w2, m = fsolve(equations, (0,0,0))
print equations((w1,w2,m))
```

In return, it gives me these (negative...) results :

```py
(0.0, -1.2378986724570495e-13, 5.1419979385514125e-13)
```

To compare, sympy gave me the results I expected. It gave approximately :

```py
(0.333333, 0.666667, 0,122515)
```

Do you have any idea why fsolve doesn't work in my case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `print equations((w1,w2,m))`, you are printing the values of  (f0,f1,f2) at the point (w1,w2,m). Instead, sympy returns the value of (w1,w2,m).

Hence, if I replace the print statement with `print (w1,w2,m)`, I get (0.6666666666319606, 0.33333333336803944, 0.12251482264361727).

The answer is different because the equations are nonlinear and can have multiple zeros.